# GIT pushing modifications to Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using GIT.  I performed several changes and did a push to Gerrit.  I received comments for updates.  As I understand, once you make the editing from comments you commit by amending the previous commit, using the same commit message, and commit it that way. So that is what I did Friday and it sent the updates to the reviewers.

Today is Monday.  When I brought up Eclipse I did a git pull and got the latest updated.  I looked at the Gerrit comments and there were a few more edits they wanted me to do (mostly deleting some comments).  I made these changes.

When I went to commit and amend the last one though it did not show a Jira story nor a change id.  The last commit message was

```
*Merge branch 'master' of http://gitscm.xxx.com/SQA-Automation/XXX-XXXXX*
```

(sorry I still am not sure whether the company name and URL are confidential or not so I just replaced them with a few XXX.

So I am not sure.  Should I just use this commit message?  I think if I do a new one it will fail when I try to push to Gerrit by giving me a "rejected" message, but even if it succeeded it would make a new review.

Any ideas what to do?  I was reading about "reset" but was confused.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you ran `git pull` before you amended the commit. Such `git-pull` causes annoying trouble especially when you use Gerrit.

You didn't specify what the "rejected" message exactly was. So I have to make a guess. You may not have the right to push a merge commit, or the push failed just because the merge commit did not have a Change-Id.

It was not necessary for you to run `git pull`. If you insist to, `git pull -r` would be better. `-r` or `--rebase` updates your local branch without creating any merge commits. A merge commit does not invoke `commit-msg` which generates a Change-Id unless you run `git commit --amend` on the merge commit.

Now you could run `git reset HEAD^ --hard` to go back to your previous commit which needs amending. Do the edits and then amend it and make sure the Change-Id is unchanged. Then, you could just push it without a pull. Let the reviewers and submitter decide if it should be rebased or just merged to the destination branch. They can do it through the Gerrit change web UI.

Comment: We do have git-bash but they encourage us to use GIT from Eclipse, which appears only to have "pull" and not "pull -r".  I could do the pull from git-bash but it sounds like you should not do a pull before a commit-amend.

Comment: @Tony In some other GUIs there is something like "rebase pull" which is equivalent to "git pull -r". "git commit --amend" rewrites the last commit of the current branch. If you run "git pull" first, the current branch may be updated and the last commit becomes a new one (a merge commit in your case). Amending the new commit is not what you need. Although the code seems okay this way, the history is messed up.